# flutter Command Generates [Unable to find git in your PATH] Unless run with Admin Privileges

Tags: flutter, git, android-studio, visual-studio-code, windows-10

After two days of searching and trying, I failed to create a flutter app in Android Studio or Visual Studio Code unless run it with Admin Privileges.

I'm using Windows 10, Git for Windows is installed correctly, and recently I decided to move it to the "**LocalAppData**" directory for testing purposes, The flutter SDK also was in C drive directly but I decided to move it to "**LocalAppData\Programs**", and in both scenarios, I failed to make [flutter] command run unless open any app "Command Prompt, PowerShell, VS Code or Android Studio" as Admin.

I've tried to add all Git and flutter "bin"'s paths in both **User Variables** and **System Variables** but failed also.

Environment Variables [Path] in both User Variables and System Variables:

```
%LocalAppData%\Git\cmd
%LocalAppData%\Git\bin
%LocalAppData%\Git\mingw64\bin
%LocalAppData%\Git\usr\bin
%LocalAppData%\Programs\flutter\bin
```

Always receive this error "**Error: Unable to find git in your PATH**.", Now I should run VS Code with Admin Privileges every time before starting work otherwise, no flutter command will work.